# HTTP GET request on website does not return full body (website scraping)

Tags: node.js, http, web-scraping, request

I am trying to scrape a website, but some pages of that website will be fully returned upon a GET request. I don't wan't to disclose the URL of said website but still I'd like to ask for help in this regard.

I've implemented HTTP requests to log into the member area of that website, which works fine. Then, I'd like to get a list of conversations, however, when I compare the response from the firefox developer tools (of the *same* GET to the *same* location with the same parameters), I will see the full HTML in firefox dev tools, but in my implementation (using the `request` nodejs module) I will only see the inner `<div id="content">...</div>`, without any javascript or surrounding HTML.

How can this be? I understand javascript can inject HTML afterwards, but how should this be possible if no javascript has been received by my scraping implementation? What is different in firefox? I understand that in firefox probably their javascript client is running and doing the GET request, which then inserts content. However, the firefox log shows a HTTP GET request (no XHR) *and* it shows the full response in the dev tools. How is this possible?

Anyone got a hint on how to proceed on this further?

Comment: Are the two requests (Firefox and nidejs) EXACTLY identical? Most likely not. For instance, check the User-Agent header. Some sites are UA-sensitive and will deliver different content for different UAs.

Comment: I made quite some efforts to resemble the requests correctly as much as I can, therefore I am using the same 1) headers 2) URL 3) URL parameters 4) body payload. Some times, I deviate a bit in terms of referrer header, but overall, it is almost 100% identical. Especially the UA header was set to the same as in the browser (`Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:74.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/74.0`).

Comment: Oh wait. You might have been right. It seems like I didnt have cache-headers in place. This seemed to make the change. In firefox caching was disabled.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: If you add your hint as reply I can accept it.